# How can I debug a React registration form that is not sending data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**show again and again the same error.**

[image: [enter image description here]()]

Here is the code please  check and do the correct because when m doing a run and passing the value than showing 'Axios error '. Please make it right and help to run this program.

i done MongoDB connection also but when m pass name,email,password. then it shows the Axios error.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from 'axios';

export default function RegisterPage() {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    
    function registerUser(e)
    {
            e.preventDefault();
             axios.post('/register'
            ,{
                name,
                email,
                password,
             });
    }

    return (
        <div className="mt-4 grow flex items-center justify-around">
            <div className="mb-30">
                <h1 className="text-4xl text-center mb-4" >Register</h1>
                <form className="max-w-md mx-auto "onSubmit={registerUser}>
                    <input type="text"
                        placeholder="Ali Khan"
                        value={name}
                        onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
                    <input type="email"
                        placeholder="your@email.com"
                        value={email}
                        onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                    <input type="password"
                        placeholder="password"
                        value={password}
                        onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                    <button className="Primary">Register</button>
                    <div className="text-center py-2 text-gray-500">
                        Already a Member? <Link className="underline" to={'/login'}>Login</Link>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

For index Page.

```
const express = require ('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose  = require('mongoose');
// const User = require('./models/User.js')
require('dotenv').config();
const app = express();
// const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

// const bcryptSalt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
app.use(cors({
    credentials:true,
    origin:'http://192.168.1.106:3000',
}));

console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL)

// moonse connection we doing here

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);


app.get('/test',(req,res)=>{
    res.json('test is ok')
});
app.use(express.json())
app.post('/register',(req,res)=>{
    const{name,email,password}=req.body;
    //  const userDoc = await User.create({
    //     name,
    //     email,
    //     password:bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcryptSalt),
    // })
    res.json(name,email,password)
});

app.listen(4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe if u add the API  full Path will work**

```js
   function registerUser(e)
    {
            e.preventDefault();
             axios.post('http://localhost:4000/register'
            ,{
                name,
                email,
                password,
             });
    }
```